# Efficiently finding a list of near matches for list of words and phrases

Tags: algorithm, sorting, indexing

I am looking for an algorithm, but I don't know the name of the problem so I can't find anything. Hopefully my explanation of the problem makes sense!

Let's say you have a long list of phrases, where each phrase is a set of words. The user inputs a list of words, and their list "matches" a phrase every word in the phrase is found in their list. A list's "score" is the number of phrases it matches. The goal is to provide the user with a list of words that would most improve their list's score.

Here's a simple example. We have ten phrases:

1. wood cabin
2. camping in woods
3. camping cabin
4. fun camping
5. bon fire
6. camping fire
7. swimming hole
8. fun cabin
9. wood fire
10. fire place

And the user provides this list:

- wood
- fun
- camping

We match phrases 1 and 4, so the score is 2. But if the user adds "cabin" to their list, they will match 3 more phrases and get a score of 5. "fire" would add 2 to the score.

With the trivially short list, there isn't any complicated problem, as you can just iterate through the options in almost no time. But as the list grows to the hundreds of thousands, it starts taking hundreds of milliseconds. It feels like there should be a way to build an index to make the process faster, but I can't think of what the index's structure would be.

Anyone who took the time to read all this, thank you! Hopefully someone knows what I'm talking about.

Comment: When there are only 3 elements in the list, why you only match phrases 1 and 4? What is counted as a "match"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map words to number of occurrences. If you use a hash table you can do it very quickly (O(N) - with N being the number of words in the phrases) - loop over all phrases, break them into words, if the word is already in the map increment its count, if not - add it to the map with count 1.

To compute the score of the input, just loop over the input words and accumulate the number of occurrences.  O(M) - this time M being the number of input words.

I doubt you can get better complexity (you need to scan the phrases at least once), and with a proper implementation of a map (available in almost all modern languages) - it will be fast as well.

Answer (score 0):

Suffix tree.

They're rather fiddly and complicated things, but basically we store a node for each character (26 * 2), then we store the suffixes for each character, so entries for th and an and so on, but presumably not for qj or other combinations which won't occur. Then you get the suffixes for those, (so the, thr, and and so on, but plenty of combinations of three letters disallowed).
It allows for very fast searching, which doesn't have to be exact. If we want to match a*d we simply follow all the suffixes of a, then only d suffixes, then we insist on nul.